# Firebase ArrayList issues (need to use GenericTypeIndicator?)

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Connecting to my Firebase database works fine when I install my app to my phone via USB. But when I install it via the Play Store, I get issues from Firebase about my ArrayList having "generic type parameters". Check out the first line of the logcat error message below:

```
09-14 15:59:55.715 4843-4843/? E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.f: Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mu.b(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mu.b(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mu.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mv.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mv.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mu.d(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mu.b(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.mu.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.b.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.test.finalapp.Activities.c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.ha.a(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.iv.b(Unknown Source)
                                                    at com.google.android.gms.c.jb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any thoughts? The Google Play version was working fine the other day and now this happened! Couldn't find any solutions online...

---

**UPDATE:**

I added the following code to my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
   -keepattributes Signature

   -keepclassmembers class com.test.finalapp.Models.** {
      *;
    }

   -keep class com.test.finalapp.CoOpStatusHolder { *; }
```

Things are working fine in database, but now I'm hit with the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.view.View]

That error is at the top of the larger logcat error:

```
 09-15 12:06:23.041 32250-32250/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                          at com.firebase.ui.a.d.b(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.em.c(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.fe.a(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.fe.c(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.dl.a(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.J(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.k(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.t(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.c(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.eg.run(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                          at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                                                          at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
                                                          at com.firebase.ui.a.d.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.em.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.fe.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.fe.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.dl.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.J(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.k(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.t(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.eg.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603) 
                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507) 
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
09-15 12:06:23.242 32250-32250/? D/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: throwable java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]

                                                         --------- beginning of crash
09-15 12:06:23.278 32250-32250/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.test.finalapp, PID: 32250
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                       at com.firebase.ui.a.d.b(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.em.c(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.fe.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.fe.c(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.dl.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.J(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.k(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.t(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.c(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.eg.run(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
                                                       at com.firebase.ui.a.d.b(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.em.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.fe.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.fe.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.dl.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.J(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.k(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.t(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.c(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.eg.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603) 
                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

CoOpStatusHolder is my FirebaseUI RecyclerView Viewholder. I made the Viewholder an inner class. I made it public static and it's in proguard-rules.pro file, so I'm still not sure what the issue is...

```
public static class CoOpStatusHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;


    public CoOpStatusHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView nameOfParentToChoose = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.
                textView_of_parent_name_in_co_op_status);
        nameOfParentToChoose.setText(name);
    }

    public void setFacebookImage(String facebookID) {
        ProfilePictureView parentFacebookPhoto = (ProfilePictureView) mView.findViewById(R.id.
                imageview_of_parent_in_co_op_status);
        parentFacebookPhoto.setProfileId(facebookID);
    }

    public void setHours(Float numofHours) {
        TextView numOfHoursForParent = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.
                textView_num_of_hours_in_co_op_other_parent_status);
        numOfHoursForParent.setText(Float.toString(numofHours));
    }


}
```

Comment: When you built your release version, it you enabled ProGuard, did you use the configuration recommended in the [Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)?

Comment: I enabled ProGuard but never knew that I had to add that Firebase code in the proguard-rules.pro file. Things were working fine for so long without the code, so I wonder why it's now suddenly an issue. Anyways, I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: That may not be the source of your problem, but should be done regardless.  To get more help, you'll need to post more information about the database read that is causing the exception.

Comment: I tried making some additions/adjustments, but now I'm hit with a new error about a (missing) view. I updated my post. Any thoughts?